# TinyMce html markup

Tags: tinymce

Is there a setting/technique which will allow me to save my **boldened** text as `<b>my text</b>` instead of `<strong>my text</strong>`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your TinyMCE configuration:

```
extended_valid_elements: "b/strong,i/em"
```

This will change `<strong>` tags to `<b>` tags and `<em>` tags to `<i>` tags.